# How can I use Scrapy to parse two different sections of source code and combine the results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have two spiders that I am currently running to scrape a single page. The spiders are shown below as Header and Detail. I have set it up like this as I do not know how to set up the beginning of the query (in this case, the variable called `listings`) to allow me to first scrape `//div[@class='patio-head']` and then `//div[@class='patio-details']` in a single step. Can someone please help me out as I would like to return the `Name` and all of the corresponding details in a single row for each URL? Thanks!

**Header**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from PatioDetail.items import PatioItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "PDSHeader"
    allowed_domains = ["http://patios.blogto.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://patios.blogto.com/patio/25-liberty-toronto/", "http://patios.blogto.com/patio/3030-dundas-west-toronto/", 
"http://patios.blogto.com/patio/3-speed/", "http://patios.blogto.com//patio/7numbers/"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    listings = hxs.select("//div[@class='patio-head']")
items = []
    for listings in listings:
        item = PatioItem()
        item ["Name"] = listings.select("div[@class='patio-head-details']/div[@class='patio-name']/h2[@class='name']/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

**Detail**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from PatioDetail.items import PatioItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "PDSDetails"
    allowed_domains = ["http://patios.blogto.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://patios.blogto.com/patio/25-liberty-toronto/", "http://patios.blogto.com/patio/3030-dundas-west-toronto/", 
"http://patios.blogto.com/patio/3-speed/", "http://patios.blogto.com//patio/7numbers/"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    listings = hxs.select("//div[@class='patio-details']")
items = []
    for listings in listings:
        item = PatioItem()
        item ["Type"] = listings.select("ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='type-icon']/div[@class='detail-line']/span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()
        item ["Covered"] = listings.select("ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='covered-icon']/div[@class='detail-line']/span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()
        item ["Heated"] = listings.select("ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='heated-icon']/div[@class='detail-line']/span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()
        item ["Capacity"] = listings.select("ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='capacity-icon last']/div[@class='detail-line']/span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sections you want is on the same page. The only thing you have to do is fetch the page and parse it for getting data from the two sections rather than fetch twice and parse twice.
Before you write a spider, you should spend some time analyzing the structure of web pages you want to fetch.

Code sample is like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    item = PatioItem()
    item['Name'] = hxs.select("//div[@class='patio-name']/h2/text()").extract()[0]
    node_type = hxs.select("//ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='type-icon']")
    item['Type'] = node_type.select(".//span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()[0]
    node_covered = hxs.select("//ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='covered-icon']")
    item['Covered'] = node_covered.select(".//span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()[0]
    node_heated = hxs.select("//ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='heated-icon']")
    item['Heated'] = node_heated.select(".//span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()[0]
    node_capacity = hxs.select("//ul[@class='detail-lister']/li[@class='capacity-icon last']")
    item['Capacity'] = node_capacity.select(".//span[@class='detail-desc']/text()").extract()[0]

    return [item,]
```

Here's a tutorial about [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). This will do you a favor :)

Comment: I get the first part of the code but you can explain how I use a temporary dict to store the data before passing them to items? I am pretty new to both Python and Scrapy so I am still learning the basics. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the code sample and link to the Xpath tutorial. I have actually read that tutorial previously but I struggled to make the leap from the simple examples in the tutorial to more complex real-world problems.

When I tried inserting your code, I received the following error: `File "PatioDetail\spiders\Details.py", line 17, in parse
            item['Type'] = node_type.xpath(".//span[@class='detail-desc']/text()
").extract()[0]
        exceptions.AttributeError: 'XPathSelectorList' object has no attribute '
xpath'`. 

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JillAtkins, sorry for my mistake using selector in scrapy and lxml. Have corrected my anwser.